# Getting weird characters when going from NSString to bytes and then back to NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, character-encoding, nsstring

```
NSString *message = @"testing";    
NSUInteger dataLength = [message lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
void *byteData = malloc( dataLength );
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [message length]);
NSUInteger actualLength = 0;
NSRange remain;
BOOL result =   [message getBytes:byteData maxLength:dataLength usedLength:&actualLength encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding options:0 range:range remainingRange:&remain];
NSString *decodedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:byteData length:actualLength encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

My issue is that I expect decodedString to be testing, but instead it looks like chinese characters.  I thought it could be an issue with null-terminated data, but it seems that that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UTF-16 byte order is getting reversed between the encode and decode.

You can do any one of the following:

- Use an encoding that specifies an explicit byte order (e.g., `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding`, `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`, `NSUTF8StringEncoding`).
- Pass `NSStringEncodingConversionExternalRepresentation` to the `options:` parameter in `getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:`.  This prepends a byte-order mark to the start of the data.
- Use `NSData`, as Elvis suggested.

These days, UTF-8 is the preferred Unicode encoding in most cases.

Comment: I used method 2.  This fixed the text, but removed a character from the end of the string.  This makes sense since it is adding a byte, but I'm not sure how to get that back.  I updated my dataLength by adding 2 to it - to account for the two bytes that I'm assuming each character is allocated to use.  Is this the correct way to do this?  I am using NSUnicodeStringEncoding because I don't want any characters to be lost/truncated.  Does that make sense?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: UTF-8 and UTF-16 are both Unicode encodings; you don't lose anything by choosing either.  NSUnicodeStringEncoding gives you UTF-16.  Most people prefer UTF-8 because it's compatible with ASCII and you don't have to worry about byte ordering.  If you want to use UTF-16, pass NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding or NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding to lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding: and that will include the BOM in the data length.

Comment: As you can tell, I'm very new to character encodings.  Previously, I thought that UTF-8 was always 8 bits and UTF-16 was always 16.  I now see that they can both be the same maximum size of 4 bytes.  So now, I don't see any benefits of using UTF-16.  Are there any?  If not, is there a NSStringEncoding for UTF-8 ( I couldn't find that documented )?  Thanks for all the info, this has been a big help.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I see there is NSUTF8StringEncoding.  When looking for it, I just looked at the descriptions for UTF-8.  Anyway - I'd appreciate any insight on my other question - are there any benefits to using UTF-16 or UTF-8.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this?

```
    NSString *message = @"testing";    
    NSData *bytes = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString* messageDecoded = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bytes encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"decoded: %@", messageDecoded);
```

Comment: I think you may be missing length in your initWithBytes call.  I actually had that previously, but thought that if I could avoid using NSData, I would like to.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid NSData?

Comment: I want to access the bytes individually - so I didn't see the need in going through NSData and then calling bytes on it to get the data if I could do it with a NSString.