# getting weird chinese characters in NSString object

Tags: xcode4.6

when I have the following code:

```
NSString *shape = @"▲";
int _length = 3;

setCardContents = [shape stringByPaddingToLength:_length withString:shape startingAtIndex:0];
```

When I put a break point right after the last line above and then check the value setCardContents, I get some weird characters at the end of my text.

From debug:
[image: screen shot from debug]

Comment: dude, I'm getting the same error here

Comment: In my case it was an encoding problem, I was guided by this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021926/getting-weird-characters-when-going-from-nsstring-to-bytes-and-then-back-to-nsst